# how a graph can be implemented using adjacency lists/sets. How does it work for directed graphs? Undirected graphs? Weighted graphs?

Tags: java, list, graph, set

Could you please give me some clue that how a graph can be implemented using adjacency lists/sets and How does it work for
directed graphs? Undirected graphs? Weighted graphs?

Comment: It is better to ask a single, specific question. For example: "How can a directed graph be implemented using adjacency lists or sets in Java"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a directed acyclic graph like this:

```
1->2 
1->3 
2->4 
2->5 
3->6 
3->7
```

Another way to view it is:

```
        1
      /   \
    2       3
  /   \   /   \
 4     5 6     7
```

This is really just a small binary tree. An adjacency list representation looks like:

```
1 -> {2, 3}
2 -> {4, 5}
3 -> {6, 7}
```

So consider that this could be a HashMap of Integers that point to Sets of Integers.

Now consider that the original graph is undirected, in other words there are parent pointers.

```
1<->2
1<->3
2<->4
2<->5
3<->6
3<->7
```

Now the representation needs more entries:

```
1 -> {2, 3}
2 -> {1, 4, 5}
3 -> {1, 6, 7}
4 -> {2}
5 -> {2}
6 -> {3}
7 -> {3}
```

Lets return to the directed version of the graph and weight it:

The weights are the first entry in the tuple and the child is the second entry. So it looks like
 `Parent->(Weight, Child)`.

```
1->(.9,2) 
1->(.1,3) 
2->(.9,4) 
2->(.1,5) 
3->(.5,6) 
3->(.5,7)
```

So 90% of the time we go from `1->2` then 90% of the time that we are at 2 we will go `2->4`.

The representation can look very similar to the directed graph:

```
1 -> {(.9,2), (.1,3)}
2 -> {(.9,4), (.1,5)}
3 -> {(.5,6), (.5,7)}
```

Hope this helps.